# DirectX10 How to use Constant Buffers

Tags: directx10

I'm trying to access some variables in my shader, but I think I'm doing this wrong. Say I have a constant buffer that looks like this:

```
cbuffer perFrame
{
    float foo;
    float bar;
};
```

I got an ID3D10EffectConstantBuffer reference to it, and I can get a specific index by calling GetMemberByIndex, but how can I figure out how many members perFrame has so that I can get each member without going out of bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `ID3DX10EffectVariable` that represents `perFrame`, then you should be able to call [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get an `ID3DX10EffectType` for `perFrame`. Then you can call [GetDesc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173717%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on that type instance to get a [D3DX10_EFFECT_TYPE_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205054%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which has a `Members` field which should give you want you need.

That said, I think accessing members by index is generally fairly brittle and that giving fields semantics whenever possible to more desirable.

Note that I have never actually tried this on structures denoted *cbuffer* so there may be some additional hoops you need to jump through if things don't quite work out -- constant buffers may have some specialized rules or handling via the effect interface. But I'm reasonably sure this will at least set you on the right track given that [constant buffers seem to be well-understood by the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173634%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: I retargetted all the links to point at the D3D10 versions and not the D3D11 versions.